# deploying production version next/image crashes heroku

Tags: heroku, next.js, nextjs-image

We have been developing a website on Heroku free with JawsDb and redis with a NodeJS multi package project. The node version is 18.14.2. Nextjs is 13.2.4

On the "free" test version, everything works fine. Now we have prepared the production version with a more beefy Jawsdb and redis server and a 1x dyno (to get started).

If we start the system and execute a curl againt any page, it works fine.

But if hit it in a brower, or curl an image, the server crashes. The system uses next/image which does some local image optimization before delivering the image. I'm assuming this somehow runs out of memory and makes the server crash for any image.

What I don't get is why the free version seems to work fine, but the "paid" production version can't handle it. I wish I could run metrics against the free version, but I can't. What could be the difference?

Memory starts at 280Mb of 512Mb. So that seems ok to start with. However, it immediately crashes on any image being loaded.

Comment: I added sharp to the installation and it seems to not crash anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was dumb but still hard to figure out. I was running a query without limit to check if any records there during startup. On test servers, the query returned perhaps max 500 records (already a lot). But on production that would be 250k. Hence the crash. I figured it out by comparing the startup sequence console output on production and developing. Fortunately, we like to log.